# SVG image size in java

Tags: java, image, svg

Why the SVG file generated using Java does not allow coordinates beyond (1000,y) ?

```
<image x='1,300' y='100' width='400' height='400' xlink:href='x.svg' />
            <image x='1,340' y='100' width='400' height='400' xlink:href='z.svg' />
```

The above image is generated but automatically start at (0,0) coordinate.

Comment: Please clarify what your question is, how you tried and post the code where you tried to solve your problem

Comment: I have multiple svg files which I am appending using StringBuilder and then generating a file using FileWriter but the problem is that the svg generated starts at (0,0) coordinate rather than the specified coordinate..@ClaudioBrasser

Comment: commas are automatically generated not included in the code.@RobertLongson

Comment: So stop automatically generating them. Provide the code that does this automatic generation in the question so we can correct it.

Comment: How do you generate the files?

Comment: <image x='1300' y='100' width='400' height='400' xlink:href='x.svg' />
            <image x='1340' y='100' width='400' height='400' xlink:href='y.svg' />@ClaudioBrasser

Comment: @Ferrybig The svg files I am using are hand wriiten and contains a circle and a rectangle. I just wanted to append both of them using java and create a new file using FileWriter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use 1,300 but 1300. The comma is why more than 1000 does not work.

Comment: Thanks, Problem was with the commas only.